# How to find an array that has a certain value and affect their values? in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array as follows:

```
 my_array =   [
      [value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4],
      [value_n1, value_n2, value_n3, value_n4],
      [value_x1, value_x2, value_x3, value_x4],
      [value_y1, value_y2, value_y3, value_y4],
      [value_z1, value_z2, value_z3, value_z4]
    ]
```

I find the array that has some value and then affect their values. For example:

```
some_value = 'xyz'
if my_array.map(&:first).include? some_value # I always compare 'some_value' with the first element of each array

  # find the array
  my_array.select{ |s| s.include? some_value }

  # affect the values with position [1], [2], [3]
  # ...

end
```

Is there a simple way to extract the array and affect their values​​?

### EXAMPLE

I have an array:

```
array = [ ['abc', 4, 5], ['xyz', 2, 10], ['ubf', 40, 9] ]
```

And a value: `x = 'abc'`

When my variable 'x' begins to compare with the arrays that I have and find the array that contain this value. Then, should add 1 to the other other values​​. So, my expected result is:

```
array = [ ['abc', **5**, **6**], ['xyz', 2, 10], ['ubf', 40, 9] ]
```

Other value: `x = 'ubf'`

Result: `array = [ ['abc', 5, 6], ['xyz', 2, 10], ['ubf', **41**, **10**] ]`

Comment: You need an example and an associated expected result.

Comment: Can more than one array match the `x` value you're looking for?

E.g., `array = [ ['abc', 4, 5], ['xyz', 2, 10], ['abc', 40, 9] ]`

Comment: @JayMitchell No. In this case no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In light of the edit of your question, I believe this is what you want.

```
my_array = [[5, 3, 1],
            [1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6],
            [7, 8, 9]]

val = 4
(ndx = my_array.transpose.first.index(val)) ?
  ((1..my_array[ndx].size-1).each { |i|
    my_array[ndx][i] += 1 }; my_array) : nil
  #=> [[5, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3], [4, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9]]

val = 7
(ndx = my_array.transpose.first.index(val)) ?
  ((1..my_array[ndx].size-1).each { |i|
    my_array[ndx][i] += 1 }; my_array) : nil
  #=> [[5, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 9, 10]]

val = 6
(ndx = my_array.transpose.first.index(val)) ?
  ((1..my_array[ndx].size-1).each { |i|
    my_array[ndx][i] += 1 }; my_array) : nil
  #=> nil
```

Comment: Please, check my example.

Answer (score 1):

Finding sub-array by its first element is a job of [`Array#assoc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-assoc) method.
Increasing value of following elements is a straightforward task. Possible implementation:

```
array = [ ['abc', 4, 5], ['xyz', 2, 10], ['ubf', 40, 9] ]
x = 'abc'

marr = array.assoc(x)
marr[1..-1] = marr.drop(1).map {|v| v+1} if marr
p array
# [["abc", 5, 6], ["xyz", 2, 10], ["ubf", 40, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along these lines:

```
my_array.map{|a| a.include?(some_value) ? transform(a) : a }

def transform array
  #return your modified array
end
```

If you fed that `[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]` and you had `some_value` set to 3, you could use

```
def transform array do
    array.map{|k| k + 1}
  end
```

to get `[[1,2], [3,4], [4,5]]`

Comment: In your example. If I only want to affect the second position for get the following result: [[1,2], [2,**4**], [3,**5**]]. How I change the function transform?

Comment: Please, check my example

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array but want it to behave in a special way, you may want to think about creating a class.

```
class EGC < Array
  def increment(val)
    self.map do |sub|
      if sub.first == val
        [val, sub[1..-1].map(&:next)].flatten
      else
        sub
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can do this:

```
e = EGC.new([["foo", 1, 2], ["bar", 3, 4]])
#=> [["foo", 1, 2], ["bar", 3, 4]]

e.increment("foo")
#=> [["foo", 2, 3], ["bar", 3, 4]]
```

Of course, you should change the names to better reflect your problem domain.

That being said, it seems that you would be better off starting with a Hash instead of a 2D Array.